# Pasar de un activity a otro en segundo plano (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Estoy realizando una aplicación Android y necesito pasar de mi activity principal a un segundo activity en el cual tomo mediante código un screen de pantalla y luego tendría que volver a mi activity principal. necesito que ese cambio de activity se haga en segundo plano, que el usuario no se entere de lo que esta pasando. Si saben como hacerlo me ayudarían muchísimo.

Este es mi código el cual se debería realizar en segundo plano (no quiero que el usuario vea esto, ni el layout enlazado a este, solo debería de ver un progress bar):

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Progress_foto.start(MainActivity2.this);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            takeScreenshot();
            Progress_foto.stop();
        }
    }, 2000); // 2 segundos de "delay"

}

private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {

        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".png";

        View u = findViewById(R.id.tabscroll);
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.tabscroll);
        //z.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
        u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
        u.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Y este es mi layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constrain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/tabscroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:background="#3C5C97"
                android:text="@string/espacio"
                android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView36"
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3C5C97"
                    android:text="@string/espacio"
                    android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FF867D"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewNumero"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewNombre"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewApellido"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView19"
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#3C5C97"
                    android:text="@string/espacio"
                    android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA1"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA2"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA3"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA4"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA5"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA6"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA7"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA8"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numA9"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB1"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB2"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB3"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB4"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB5"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB6"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB7"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB8"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numB9"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC1"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC2"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC3"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC4"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC5"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC6"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC7"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC8"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/buscar_numC9"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView20"
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#3C5C97"
                    android:text="@string/espacio"
                    android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:background="#3C5C97"
                android:text="@string/espacio"
                android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste, esto se ha preguntado anteriormente, si tratas de realizar una captura debería ser en "foreground" por seguridad, de otra forma no se permitirá.

Comment: @Jorgesys actualice con mi código el cual debería realizarse en segundo plano, sin que el usuario se entere de ello.

Comment: Gracias por agregar el código, aquí puedes hacer uso de un servicio para realizar el proceso en segundo plano, pero sabes el problema puede ser tratar de obtener el Screenshot en segundo plano :-(, espero equivocarme, en un tiempo que tenga reviso si es posible de alguna forma.

Comment: Dale muchas gracias por tu atención. investigue bastante pero tampoco encontré por ningún lado, no se me ocurre otra alternativa :(